# VBA: Using custom data types and functions to return array ( array (), array() )

Tags: arrays, vba, custom-data-type

This is extension of an earlier question which was answered and solved. Trying to make an array of arrays and encountered the same error "only user defined types in public object modules can be coerced ...."

I am looking into using Collection but not yet figured that out.

```
Option Explicit

Public Type aType
    P_Col As Integer
    P_Rad As Single
    P_X As Single
    P_Y As Single
End Type

Public Type bType
    Shp1() As aType
    Shp2() As aType
    Shp3() As aType
End Type



Function MakePatterns() As bType()
Dim i       As Integer
Dim circles()   As aType
Dim triangles() As aType
Dim squares()   As aType
Dim shps()      As bType


For i = 1 To 5
    ReDim Preserve circles(i)
    circles(i).P_Col = Int(i / 2)
    circles(i).P_Rad = i
    circles(i).P_X = i * 10 + 1
    circles(i).P_Y = i * 10 + 5
Next

For i = 1 To 5
    ReDim Preserve triangles(i)
    triangles(i).P_Col = Int(i / 2)
    triangles(i).P_Rad = i
    triangles(i).P_X = i * 10 + 1
    triangles(i).P_Y = i * 10 + 5
Next

For i = 1 To 5
    ReDim Preserve squares(i)
    squares(i).P_Col = Int(i / 2)
    squares(i).P_Rad = i
    squares(i).P_X = i * 10 + 1
    squares(i).P_Y = i * 10 + 5
Next

For i = 1 To 5
    ReDim Preserve shps(i)
    shps(i) = Array(circles(i), triangles(i), squares(i))
Next

'For i = 1 To 5
'    Debug.Print circles(i).P_Col; circles(i).P_Rad; _
'     circles(i).P_X; circles(i).P_Y
'Next

MakePatterns = shps

End Function
```

Comment: If you know the number of elements, it's better to use arrays and resize them only once. For example `Dim circles(1 To 5) As aType`

Comment: Thanks Slai. Actually, the number of elements is not always identical. Perhaps I should not have simplified it to all having 5. In fact, I am unsure about how to handle dissimilar dimensions without leaving a trail of empty elements in the returned array.

If circles(10), triangles(4), squares(56), I was thinking about doing it for 56 times (maximum ubound) and leaving lots of empty .shp1 and .shp2. Otherwise I was thinking about doing separate loops for each.

Comment: [`Scripting.Dictionary`](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3667/scripting-dictionary-object) should be a bit easier than [`Collection`](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/5838/collections)

Comment: @Slai, will need to read up on Dictionary again as well, been very shy about using either to date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the thing throwing your exception is that you used arrays of type `aType` for `Shp1` and so on. Later on, you implemented it as it was just a type of `aType`, not an array of `aType`.

Now, based on your answer I came up with this code. You will end up with 5 elements of `bType` each containing 5 elements of `aType`. However, you can change this as you desire, point is, you now have an array of type `bType` containing arrays of type `aType` to host circles, triangles and squares.

```
Option Explicit

Public Type aType
    P_Col As Integer
    P_Rad As Single
    P_X As Single
    P_Y As Single
End Type

Public Type bType
    circles()     As aType
    triangles()   As aType
    squares()     As aType
End Type

Function MakePatterns() As bType()
Dim i, j        As Integer
Dim shps()      As bType


ReDim shps(4)
For i = LBound(shps) To UBound(shps)

      For j = 0 To 4
         ReDim Preserve shps(i).circles(j)
         With shps(i).circles(j)
            .P_Col = Int(j / 2)
            .P_Rad = j
            .P_X = j * 10 + 1
            .P_Y = j * 10 + 5
         End With
      Next j

      For j = 0 To 4
         ReDim Preserve shps(i).triangles(j)
         With shps(i).triangles(j)
            .P_Col = Int(j / 2)
            .P_Rad = j
            .P_X = j * 10 + 1
            .P_Y = j * 10 + 5
         End With
      Next j

      For j = 0 To 4
         ReDim Preserve shps(i).squares(j)
         With shps(i).squares(j)
            .P_Col = Int(j / 2)
            .P_Rad = j
            .P_X = j * 10 + 1
            .P_Y = j * 10 + 5
         End With
      Next j

Next i

MakePatterns = shps

End Function
```

Two more hints:

- If you already know you want to have 5 items, declare the array with 5 items instead of resizing it constantly.
- The array's indexes start at zero, so you might want to change your loops to `For i=0 To 4`. Otherwise you end up having a first object of type `bType` containing only items of `aType` that have the value 0 in each property.

Comment: Thanks you Codeguy. Now corrected as suggested.

Actually, shp1, shp2 and shp3 originally had different dimensions and I made them all 5 just for simplicity. If they are different, presumably I would have to do Shps(i).shp1, Shps(i).shp2 and so on in separate loops or risk filling the shorter ones with "0"s, right? Or is it a case of finding the max UBound and loop for that number of times?

Thanks also for the zero base reminder and yes, I have been seeing the "0"s in the first element!!

Comment: No problem, happy to help. 
Now the solution provided, an element of type `bType` always consists of three elements of  `aType`. What do you want the `bType` element to consist of? Do you want it to consist of three _arrays_ of elements of type `aType`?

Comment: bType and aType both have fixed number of elements, but not the same. What I was wondering is Shp1(i) and Shp2(i) and Shp3(i) which may not have the same lengths. So shp(i) may be say (Shp1(5), Shp2(9), Shp3(2)), and I am using three loops to fill shp(i).Shp1(), shp(i).Shp2() and shp(i).Shp3(), which seems inefficient. Alternatively, I have set one loop with 9 counts (highest uBound) but end up with empty contents in Shp1 and Shp3 which is a bit ugly. Is there a better way to handle this perhaps? Thanks again.

Comment: I don't really understand your goal with the type `bType`. Generally, there are two options: you can either use only one element of type `bType` that can host _n_ circles, _n_ triangles and _n_ squares, the _n_ 's not needing to be the same number for each shape. The other option is to do it using the code that you already have by now and just ReDim the `shps` to the biggest `UBound` of `circles`, `squares` or `triangles`, however, you'll possibly end up with a lot of elements of type `aType` having all their values set to 0. (e.g. 10 circles and 2 squares -> 8 squares with 0-values).

Comment: Sorry, I got myself into a muddle. Presumably, with shps as bType, I only have Dim shps(3) As bType, since it contains Circles(i), Triangles(i), Squares(i); is this the right way of looking at it?

As for Circles(), Triangles() and Squares(), they can vary.

Say if I were to pick 10 items from a bag containing these three shapes in two colours, say green and red, I have two boxes, for red and for green. Within each of these boxes, I have three jars, one for each shape. 

Trying to make the box bType, the jars aType, and within the jars, I am interested in the shapes' sizes and mass.

Comment: I am trying to get around returning multiple array variables of different sizes from one function by packing them inside another array variable.

Comment: @user110084 does the updated answer suit your needs?

Comment: Very much so @codeguy Thank you. I did end up trying both this way, separate loops as well as leaving blank elements and I much prefer the separate loops. Thanks so much. I also tried keeping each of the TYPE elements as individual arrays just to explore, and noticed that using custom TYPE seemed to run much slower for the same number of loops. Is that normally the case with custom TYPE?